# Speed improvement for root finding

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

I'm wondering whether it is possible to speed up the following code that I'm using to find points on the intersection between a line and the zero locus of an equation.

The idea is the following. First, generate two points $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{q}$ randomly on the 9-dimensional sphere. Each of these points is given as a 5-vector of complex numbers (viewing 10 real coordinates as 5 complex coordinates). Using these two points, you can parametrise a line in 5 complex dimensions as
$$\vec{l}(t) = \vec{p} + t\, \vec{q},$$
where $t$ parametrises where on the line you are.

I then want to find the intersection of this line with the equation
$$Q(\vec{z}) \equiv z_1^4+\ldots+z_5^4 = 0 ,$$
where $(z_1,\ldots,z_5)$ are again complex coordinates. (In the full problem, $Q(z)$ is actually of arbitrary degree and so I cannot find the roots of $Q=0$ analytically.) The intersection is given by
$$Q(\vec{p} + t\, \vec{q})=0,$$
which is then a quartic equation for $t$. There are generically 4 solutions $t_i$ to such an equation. Substituting these values of $t$ back into $\vec{l}(t)$, we find 4 points (4 sets of coordinates $\vec{z}_i=\vec{l}(t_i)$) where the line intersects $Q=0$.

I then repeat this using many randomly generated points $\vec{p}$ and $\vec{q}$ to get a large number of points (usually on the order of 5-10 million).

My problem is that even for 1M points, this takes roughly 90s or so, which is a good chunk of the total runtime of my calculation. At the moment, I have a compiled function that finds the random points on the sphere (by sampling a normal distribution and then scaling the length of the vector to 1), a non-compiled function that does the root finding, and then a final `ParallelTable` function that repeats this for as many points as I want (and converts the result to a packed array, since I then do some numerical linear algebra with it).

I'd be very interested in any way to speed this up. I come back to this every month or so, and fail at squeezing anymore speed out of it.

I was hoping to get some improvement from compiling the root-finding function as this seems to be the slowest part, but couldn't see a way to do this. I was also wondering if generating all of the random points on the sphere first and then using `Listable` in some capacity might help, but again I couldn't quite see how to get this to work.

A nagging voice in the back of my head says I should just use C instead, but I've been amazed at how close Mathematica can usually get, so I'm not giving up yet! Thanks for the taking the time to read this!

The code is:

```
(* define equation we want to solve for Q=0 *)
(* quartic equation so generically 4 roots *)
degree=4;
dim=5;


(* equation of the form z[[1]]^degree+... *)
Q[z_]:=Sum[z[[i]]^degree,{i,1,dim}];


(* compiled function to generate a random point on a (2*d-1)-dimensional sphere *)
(* express as a complex point in C^d *)
genPoint$S=Compile[{{d,_Integer}},
Module[{x},
(* generate a 2*d-vector (a point) in R^(2*d) using rotationally symmetric normal distribution *)
x=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[],2d];

(* normalise vector to 1, giving a point on sphere S^(2*d-1) *)
x=x/Norm[x];

(* convert real 10-vector to complex 5-vector (view as point in C^dim) *)
Part[x,1;;d]+ I Part[x,d+1;;2 d]],
"RuntimeOptions"->"Speed",CompilationOptions->{"InlineExternalDefinitions"->True},RuntimeAttributes->Listable,Parallelization->True];


(* Function to generate degree # of points by intersecting the line (p + tq) with Q=0 *)
(* t is variable that we solve for *)
genPoint[d_]:=Module[{t,line}, 
(* define line as (p + tq) where p and q are random points on S^(2*dim - 1) written as complex 5-vectors *)
line=genPoint$S[d]+t genPoint$S[d];

(* solve for t in Q(p+tq)=0 - find degree=4 solutions as Q is quartic *)
(* substitute solutions back into (p + tq) to find points *)
(* get 4 x dim array as output - 4 sets of points, each specified by a complex 5-vector *)
line/.{NRoots[Q[line]==0,t,Method->"JenkinsTraub"]//ToRules}]


(* function to generate at least N points that lie on Q = 0 *)
findPoints[d_,deg_,N_]:=Module[{output},
output=Developer`ToPackedArray[Flatten[ParallelTable[genPoint[d],{i,1,Ceiling[N/deg]}],1]];
output]


genPoint$S[dim]//Dimensions//AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0004921`,{5}} *)
genPoint[dim]//Dimensions//AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.0013839`,{4,5}} *)

(* timing for at least 1000000 points *)
findPoints[dim,degree,1000000]//Dimensions//AbsoluteTiming
(* {90.7323466`,{1000000,5}} *)
```

Edit: I've managed to find a ~20% improvement by batching the computation of the points on the sphere. It also produces a packed array by default. The new code is simply:

```
(*define equation we want to solve for Q=0*)
(*quartic equation so generically 4 roots*)
degree=4;
dim=5;

(*equation of the form z[[1]]^degree+...*)
Q[z_]:=Sum[z[[i]]^degree,{i,1,dim}];

findPoints$test[d_,deg_,N_]:=(

x=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[],{Ceiling[N/deg],2d}];
y=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[],{Ceiling[N/deg],2d}];

x=x/(Norm/@x);
y=y/(Norm/@y);

cx=Part[x, All, 1 ;; d] + I Part[x, All, 1 + d ;; 2 d];
cy=Part[y, All, 1 ;; d] + I Part[y, All, 1 + d ;; 2 d];

lines=cx + t cy;

Flatten[(#/.{NRoots[Q[#]==0,t,Method->"JenkinsTraub"]//ToRules})&/@lines,{{1,2},{3}}])

findPoints$test[dim, degree, 1000000]//Dimensions//AbsoluteTiming
(* {72.7542245`,{1000000,5}} *)
```

Comment: Does it improve if you set `"CompilationTarget"->"C"`?

Comment: Also, if getting the random sphere directions is the bottleneck, there is a way to do that using uniform distributions on intervals (Box Muller method). Not sure if your code does that under the hood.

Comment: Hi! There seems to be basically no difference when I use C instead of WVM (within 5% of each other).

Regarding generating the random points on the sphere, I figured using the normal distribution (which can be compiled) would be as fast / faster than generating points on the interval. I was originally using points on the interval and then projecting to the sphere, which I don't think is as clever as Box Muller - I'll have a look at that.

Comment: I've added an edit above with some slightly simpler code that batches the computation of the sphere points together. This gives about a 20% speed improvement, but I still feel like there is some improvement to be found...

Comment: I should add, the original reason I used `ParallelTable` is that it reduced the runtime when I was working on a computer with 4+ cores. I was hoping the new implementation would be able to take advantage of multiple cores. I'm sure I could do this by splitting the calculation and using `ParallelDo`, but I was hoping for a `Compile`-based solution that would take care of this all with `Parallelisation->True`.

Comment: Last code takes 9.41695 s on my computer with `Parallelize[ , Method -> "CoarsestGrained"]`

Comment: Where about's are you using that? If I wrap that around `findPoints$test[dim, degree, 1000000]` then I get a warning of "cannot be parallelized; proceeding with sequential evaluation", and a timing just a little slower than not using it at all. If I wrap it around `(#/.{NRoots[Q[#]==0,t,Method->"JenkinsTraub"]//ToRules})&/@lines` in the function definition then it ends up taking 160s instead of 72s.

Comment: Try to use it as follows `findPoints$test[d_, deg_, N_] := Parallelize[(), Method -> "CoarsestGrained"]`

Comment: On my current PC (a dual core), your suggested placement of Parallelize leads to approximately the same execution time as not using Parallelize. However there are no errors and the execution time does not balloon as when I tried to use it elsewhere. I believe that on a computer with more cores, I will indeed see the improvement you suggested (I have an eight-core machine coming soon so should be able to check this). Thank you!

Comment: You said in a comment to the deleted answer that you were particularly interested in a Q that is degree 5 in the z. Of course degree 5 polynomials don't have a solution in radicals. Degree 4 polynomials do, and it is possible to vectorize root finding of degree 4 polynomials, achieving a large speed up. Of course this approach won't work at all for degree 5 polynomials. So, is there any benefit to providing an answer using this appoach?

Comment: Hi Carl! Thanks for thinking about this, but I don't believe so. I've updated the question to reflect the fact that the general problem is of arbitrary degree. I figure if I do want to implement something analytic for lower degrees, I can find the analytic solution, compile the expressions for the roots, then use `Listable` to vectorise it. I already have some code for this for some other functions I need to evaluate many times.

Comment: Hm. Numerical root finding typically profits from good initial guesses. One could exploit this as follows: Rewrite the random point generation as a Markov chain with decently small increments. Then you can use the solutions of the old point pair as initial guesses for the new point pair and perform a few Newton iterations. If Newton's method converges: Fine. Otherwise, use NRoots as fallback. If the Markov chain is sufficiently long, you still get the product of sphere uniformuly covered.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Can you show some code for this problem with Newton iterations and Markov chine?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Well, creating a suitable Markov chain is not difficult: Given unit vectors `p` and `q`, some random vectors `u` and `v` (e.g., uniformly sampled from the unit ball), and `0< r < 1/2`, create new vectors by `pnew = #/Sqrt[#.#]&[p+ r u]` and `qnew = #/Sqrt[#.#]&[q+ r v]`. Then apply Newton's method `deg` times, using each of the solutions for `p` and `q` as a starting point. If `r` is chosen small, then Newton's method typically converges very quickly. If `r` is chose a bit larger, the Markov chain has better mixing properties and approaches the uniform distribution a bit faster.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Implementing this should be straight-forward, but a bit fiddly. Newton's method has to be applied only to a real $2 \times 2$-system, so the inverse if the derivative of `Q` with respect to `{Re[t], Im[t]}` can be written down directly, so that `LinearSolve` is not needed. So the whole procedure can be compiled. The fallback routine is a bit more of an issue, because that one cannot be compiled. But maybe it is not needed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code devoted for testing to demonstrate effect of parallel job. Let take number of kernels used  equal `nk`, then we can distribute computation as follows

```
SeedRandom[1234](*we set randomizer for testing only!*); degree = 4;
dim = 5;
LaunchKernels[]; nk = $KernelCount;

Q[z_] := Sum[z[[i]]^degree, {i, 1, dim}];

findPoints$test[d_, deg_, N_, 
   i_] := (x = 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {Ceiling[N/deg], 2 d}];
   y = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {Ceiling[N/deg], 2 d}];
   x = x/(Norm /@ x);
   y = y/(Norm /@ y);
   cx = Part[x, All, 1 ;; d] + I Part[x, All, 1 + d ;; 2 d];
   cy = Part[y, All, 1 ;; d] + I Part[y, All, 1 + d ;; 2 d];
   lines = cx + t cy;
   root[i] = 
    Flatten[(# /. {NRoots[Q[#] == 0, t, Method -> "JenkinsTraub"] // 
           ToRules}) & /@ lines, {{1, 2}, {3}}]);
```

In the case with `nk=4` we have

```
Parallelize[
  Table[findPoints$test[dim, degree, 1000000/nk, i] // Dimensions, {i,
     nk}], Method -> "FinestGrained"] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[]= {19.8538, {{250000, 5}, {250000, 5}, {250000, 5}, {250000, 
   5}}}
```

With other options we have same result, for example,

```
Parallelize[
  Table[findPoints$test[dim, degree, 1000000/nk, i] // Dimensions, {i,
     nk}], Method -> Automatic] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[]= {20.8837, {{250000, 5}, {250000, 5}, {250000, 5}, {250000, 
   5}}}
```

This result found out with 50% CPU. With 100% CPU it takes 10 s and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Edit

Tried an anylytical solution as shown below.

**Sorry, but didn't see a programming error. So it turned out that it is much slower. I show it anyway.**

Learn, how anylytical solutions look like ...

```
p = {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}; q = {q1, q2, q3, q4, q5};

Q[z_] := Total@(z^4)

sol[{p1_, p2_, p3_, p4_, p5_}, {q1_, q2_, q3_, q4_, q5_}] = 
   t /. Solve[Q[p + t q] == 0, t, Quartics -> False]
```

Solution writen in vector form is

Clear[p, q, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, q1, q2, q3, q4, q5]

```
sol4 = {Root[p .p^3 + (4 p^3 .q) #1 + (6 p^2 .q^2) #1^2 + (4  p.q^3) #1^3 + (q .q^3) #1^4 &, 1], 
   Root[p .p^3 + (4 p^3 .q) #1 + (6 p^2 .q^2) #1^2 + (4 p.q^3) #1^3 + (q .q^3) #1^4 &, 2], 
   Root[p .p^3 + (4 p^3 .q) #1 + (6 p^2 .q^2) #1^2 + (4 p.q^3) #1^3 + (q .q^3) #1^4 &, 3], 
   Root[p .p^3 + (4 p^3 .q) #1 + (6 p^2 .q^2) #1^2 + (4 p.q^3) #1^3 + (q .q^3) #1^4 &, 4]
};
```

Analysing gives Roots as a Binomial sum of p and q vector.

```
rsum[d_] := 
 p.p^(d - 1) + 
 Sum[(Binomial[d, j] p^(d - j) . q^j ) #1^j, {j, 1, d - 1}] + 
 q.q^(d - 1) #1^d

sol[d_] := Table[Root[Evaluate[rsum[d]] &, k], {k, 1, d}]

sol[4] == sol4  (*   True   *)
```

Your function to generate points

```
genPoint$S = 
 Compile[{{d, _Integer}}, 
 Module[{x},(*generate a 2*d-vector (a point) in R^(2*
d) using rotationally symmetric normal distribution*)
x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 2 d];
(*normalise vector to 1,giving a point on sphere S^(2*d-1)*)
x = x/Norm[x];
(*convert real 10-vector to complex 5-vector (view as point in  C^
dim)*)Part[x, 1 ;; d] + I Part[x, d + 1 ;; 2 d]], 
"RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed", 
CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, Parallelization -> True]

{pp, qq} = {genPoint$S[5], genPoint$S[5]}

ss[p_, q_] = Evaluate[sol[6]]; 
pp + # qq & /@ ss[pp, qq] // TableForm
```

Here dimension 6

```
(ss[p_, q_] = Evaluate[sol[6]]; 
 ParallelTable[({pp, qq} = {genPoint$S[5], genPoint$S[5]};
  pp + # qq & /@ ss[pp, qq]), {10000}];) // AbsoluteTiming
```